# Is this homebrew Eldritch Invocation, Eyes of the Ooze, balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, warlock, eldritch-invocations, homebrew-review

I've been trying to homebrew an Eldritch Invocation that grants the Warlock blindsight, but I'm not sure how far this blindsight should extend. I initially thought to compare it to the pre-existing invocation Devil's Sight, which grants 120 feet of darkvision through magical and non-magical darkness, but blindsight is (obviously) far superior to darkvision, so I deserted that comparison.

Here is the current form of this Eldritch Invocation:

> ## Eyes of the Ooze
>
> *No Prerequisites*
>
> You gain blindsight that reaches up to 15 feet.

Is this Eldritch Invocation balanced?

Comment: Note: Devil's Sight doesn't grant darkvision. It lets the Warlock completely ignore darkness, which is _better_ than darkvision... but RAI it doesn't let the Warlock ignore Dim Light, which is _worse_ than darkvision.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Possibly not

As is, this invocation can be troublesome, especially at early levels. Blindsight grants a way to deal with invisible creatures/objects/traps in close range, something low-level characters can only do through the *[see invisibility](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/see-invisibility)* spell, a 2nd-level spell. Once you get the invocation, you have an unlimited resource for that kind of situation.

[Rogues](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue) gains a feature similar to blindsight only at 14th level (!), Blindsense:

> Starting at 14th level, if you are able to hear, you are aware of the location of any hidden or invisible creature within 10 feet of you.

I would recommend a level prerequisite of 15 for this invocation (as it is better than the 14th level feature a rogue gets). The warlock invocation Witch Sight – that grants a sense similar to [truesight](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#Senses) (excluding the ability to see in magical darkness and the Ethereal Plane), has a 15th level prerequisite.

Comment: If I added the level 15 prerequisite as you suggested, would it be reasonable to increase the range of the blindsight to 30 feet like Witch Sight, or should I keep it at the original 15 feet?

Comment: @aletteroradigit I would use the same wording of the Rogue feature. Witch Sight is not really truesight, just like the Rogue feature isn't blindsight.